# Rotating a point about another point - wrong direction

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

I currently have a working piece of code that rotates one point about another.  The issue is that when the user inputs '90' I want that to be a rotation to the horizontal axis, where currently 90 degrees point down (vertical axis).  Here's a diagram to clarify:
[image]

And here's the current code that I have:

```
    public static Point RotatePoint(Point pointToRotate, Point centerPoint, int angleInDegrees) {
        double angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * (Math.PI / 180);
        double cosTheta = Math.Cos(angleInRadians);
        double sinTheta = Math.Sin(angleInRadians);
        int x = (int)
                (cosTheta * (pointToRotate.X - centerPoint.X) -
                sinTheta * (pointToRotate.Y - centerPoint.Y) + centerPoint.X);
        int y = (int)
                (sinTheta * (pointToRotate.X - centerPoint.X) +
                cosTheta * (pointToRotate.Y - centerPoint.Y) + centerPoint.Y);
    }
```

I've tried making y=x and vice versa, as well as trying to fudge the data on the way in, but no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can't you just subtract 90 from the user input?

Comment: Two issues: firstly I have tested the code and it does not show the behaviour depicted on "Current", that is, clockwise positive, but right the contrary and thus the suggestion of @ChrisSinclair should be acceptable. The second issue is: what is the exact point of the reference angles? (0, 90, etc.) Its only utility is for the polar coordinate system (e.g., the point is located at distance X and Y degrees), but the outputs from the function are cartesian coordinates. Thus the only thing which really matters is the orientation (+ means clockwise or counter-).

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Nope, doesn't quite work; only for the case where I want the current horizontal line to point down.  subtracting 90 degrees from the vertical line make it point left instead.

Comment: @varocarbas I use the function to rotate and 'end point' about a 'start point' and then draw a line from start -> end.  The current implementation rotates it CCW.  Though when rendered it appears as CW since its being drawn to a canvas: (0,0) is upper left, (Max X, 0) is upper right, (0, Max Y) is bottom left

Comment: I think that you need to clarify your ideas a bit; please, take a look  at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said via comment, the calculations in the included function are fine: the rotated point is calculated as expected (negative angles imply clockwise rotation). What you are after is the definition of the rotated point based on a polar system of coordinates and this has to be done at a later stage. The system of reference depicted in "Desired" has a +90-degree gap with respect to the "default system of reference" and thus you just have to add +90 to the calculations peformed for such a system.

The angle you are after can be calculated by relying on the following functions:

```
public static double angleFromPoint(Point inputPoint, Point centerPoint)
{
    double varX1 = Math.Abs(inputPoint.X - centerPoint.X);
    double varY1 = Math.Abs(inputPoint.Y - centerPoint.Y);

    double outAngle = 180 * Math.Atan(varY1 / varX1) / Math.PI; //Angle from 0 to 90 which has to be updated on account of the quadrant it is in and the chosen syst

    int curQuadrant = determineQuadrant(inputPoint, centerPoint);

    //Modifications to account for the default system of reference
    if (curQuadrant == 1)
    {
        outAngle = 180 - outAngle;
    }
    else if (curQuadrant == 3)
    {
        outAngle = 360 - outAngle;
    }
    else if (curQuadrant == 4)
    {
        outAngle = 180 + outAngle;
    }

    //Over-modification to account for the system of reference "Desired", +90 the default system of reference
    outAngle = outAngle + 90;


    if (outAngle > 360)
    {
        outAngle = outAngle - 360;
    }

    return outAngle;
}

//Moving clockwisely, the first quadrant is located between 180 and 90 degrees in the default system of reference 
public static int determineQuadrant(Point inputPoint, Point centerPoint)
{
    int curQuadrant = 0;

    if (inputPoint.X < centerPoint.X && inputPoint.Y >= centerPoint.Y)
    {
        //Default system of reference -> 180 to 90
        curQuadrant = 1;
    }
    else if (inputPoint.X >= centerPoint.X && inputPoint.Y >= centerPoint.Y)
    {
        //Default system of reference -> 90 to 0/360
        curQuadrant = 2;
    }
    else if (inputPoint.X >= centerPoint.X && inputPoint.Y < centerPoint.Y)
    {
        //Default system of reference -> 0/360 to 270
        curQuadrant = 3;
    }
    else if (inputPoint.X < centerPoint.X && inputPoint.Y < centerPoint.Y)
    {
        //Default system of reference -> 270 to 180
        curQuadrant = 4;
    }

    return curQuadrant;
}
```

There you can see a step-by-step, clear calculation based on the "default system of reference" and the subsequent transformation to the one you want. The calculations are based on ArcTangent (delivering just 0-90 angles) and updated on account of the given "quadrant" (based on the default system, that is, -90 the desired system); the calculated angle+90 delivers the result you want.

Thus you have to firstly calculate the coordinates for the rotated point and then the associated angle:

```
Point rotatedPoint = RotatePoint(curPointnew, centerPoint, rotationAngle);
double angleRotatedPoint = angleFromPoint(rotatedPoint, centerPoint);
```